# why exponential time is applied only to size in pseudo-polynomial time complexity

Tags: algorithm

i have been searching about pseudo-polynomial time.
i have unresolved question about it.
for example, 0-1 knapsack algorithm's time complexity is O(NW).
N is the number of items and W is the size of knapsack.
it is pseudo-polynomial because time complexity is O(N X 2<sup>bits in W</sup>).

then, i think O(2<sup>bits in N</sup> X 2<sup>bits in W</sup>) is possible for time complexity. but why 0-1 knapsack algorithm is pseudo-polynomial only due to 'W' not 'N'?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is about the size of the input, not its value. `N` is the size of an array. `W` is just a value.

I like to think it is pseudo-polynomial because it behaves exponentially if we encode the `W` in binary (or greater) representation, but if we encode the `W` in [unary representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system), it behaves "polynomially".

But for `N` this isn't true. No mater which representation we encode the input array, the time function will always behave as a polynomial.

#### In practice

This has a practical result in how easy it is to create an input that takes too long to process. If we want to attack on `N`, we must create an array with `N` elements. But if we choose `W`, it is as easy as creating an array with a single big value (using `log2 W` bits).

Answer (score 0):

Note that `N` indicates the number of elements you have, each element is represented as `(w_i,c_i)` (weight, cost) - so overall the input size is `Omega(n)` - since it must contain all `n` elements.

However, `W` is a size, and the input contains only the number, but since you need log(W) bits to represent the size, the input size is `Omega(log(W))`

In conclusion, we say knapsack (for example) is pseudo polynomial - because it is NOT polynomial in the size of the INPUT, it is exponential in it, since it takes `O(N*2^b)` time, and the input size is `O(N+b)` - so it takes exponential time relative to the input size.